# Z3's OCaml library throws segmentation fault

Tags: ocaml, z3

Consider the following OCaml code snippet that uses Z3 module to interface with the Z3 solver. The code tries to define a new `TPair` datatype in Z3 with a single constructor `T` that accepts two integer arguments:

```
open Z3                                                                                         
open Z3.SMT
open Z3.Expr                                                                                    
open Z3.Symbol                                                                                  
open Z3.Datatype                                                                                
open Z3.FuncDecl
open Z3.Arithmetic 
open Z3.Arithmetic.Integer                                                                      
open Z3.Quantifier

let _ =                                                                                         
  let cfg = [("model", "true"); ("proof", "false")] in
  let ctx = (mk_context cfg) in 
  let sym = Symbol.mk_string ctx in
  let s_Int = mk_sort ctx in
  (* (declare-datatypes () ((TPair (T Int Int) )))*)
  let s_T = mk_constructor_s ctx "T" (sym "isT") 
               [sym "left"; sym "right"]                                                        
               [Some s_Int; Some s_Int] [0; 0] in                                               
  let s_TPair = mk_sort_s ctx "TPair" [s_T] in
  let _::s_content::_ = Constructor.get_accessor_decls s_T in                                   
  let s_isT = Constructor.get_tester_decl s_T in                                                
  let solver = Solver.mk_solver ctx None in
    begin 
      Printf.printf "*****  CONTEXT ******\n";                                                  
      print_string @@ Solver.to_string solver;
      Printf.printf "\n*********************\n"
    end
```

The calls to `get_tester_decl` and `get_accessor_decls` both throw segmentation fault. What could be the reason?

Comment: Report it to the library author.

Comment: The example source code given here compiles (with warnings) and runs fine for me. OCaml is a bit flakey. Could you tell us which version precisely you are using and where you got that from? Also, make sure you're using the latest Z3 source code and compile it from source as there have been a number of fixes since the last binary release.

Answer (score 1):

No code, written in pure OCaml, can cause a segmentation fault. This is because OCaml is a memory safe language. The problem is somewhere in the plumbing, either in the place where OCaml is bound to the underlying library, on in the z3 library itself.

Only library (or bindings) authors can help you in debugging and fixing this issue. So please, create an issue in [the upstream](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) repository.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The question is intended for the Z3 community, so I removed the OCaml tag. Any reason you re-added it?

Comment: Sure, the question explicitly stated OCaml both in the title and in the body, it also included OCaml code. It also looks like that OP thinks, that the problem in OCaml or in his code, not in the library. So, my task was to explain, that OCaml by itself can't be a reason for such problems, so the root of the problem should be looked elsewhere. I hope, that in future my answer will help someone who will search  for "segmentation fault + ocaml" , by explicitly saying, that the problem can't be in the OCaml code.